# In noetherian domains, do we have $x \in P^{n-1} \setminus P^n,xy \in P^n \implies y \in P$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, noetherian, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $R$ be a noetherian integral domain, let $P$ be a non zero prime ideal of $R$ and let $x,y \in R$. Assume that for some $n \geq 1$, we have $x \in P^{n-1} \setminus P^n$ and $xy \in P^n$. Does it follow that $y \in P$ ?

This is true if $R$ is a Dedekind domain. Indeed, $x$ has $P$-valuation $n-1$ and $xy$ has $P$-valuation at least $n$, so that 
$$v_P(y) = v_P(xy)-v_P(x) \geq n-(n-1) = 1$$
and $y \in P$. I tried to do it by induction on $n$, but we don't have $P^{n} \setminus P^{n+1} \subset P^{n-1} \setminus P^{n}$... Otherwise we would have been done.

If $R$ is only an integral domain or if $P$ is not prime, this could fail, I believe. Anyway, any hint would be helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: I'd try the example of prime ideal whose square is not primary given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_ideal).

Comment: As a side comment, the conclusion is true if $P^n$ is $P$-primary. This holds if e.g. $P$ is maximal, explaining why it works for Dedekind domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the useful hint given by [user26857](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2001721/in-noetherian-domains-do-we-have-x-in-pn-1-setminus-pn-xy-in-pn-impli#comment4110178_2001721) above, we can try the example 3, p. 51, in chap. 4 of *Introduction to commutative algebra* (Atiyah, MacDonald) :

$$ R = k[X,Y,Z]/(XY-Z^2),\quad  P = (x,z)$$
where $x,y,z$ denote the equivalence classes of $X,Y,Z$ respectively.
Notice that $P$ is a prime ideal of the noetherian *integral* domain $R$ (since $z^2-xy$ is Eisenstein at $p=x$ in $k[x,y][z]$).

We have
$$x \in P \setminus P^2,\quad
xy = z^2 \in P^2, \quad
y \not \in P$$
because $Y \not \in (X,Z,XY-Z^2)$ for degree reasons and $X \not \in (X^2,XZ,Z^2,XY-Z^2)$ also for degree reasons. Therefore the intial claim is wrong in general.

Comment: $Y \not \in (X,Z,XY-Z^2)$ can be shown just by evaluating at $(0,1,0)$.